# How to nest ng-view inside ng-include?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-view

When trying to add an `ng-view` inside an `ng-include`, nothing happens. e.g. in the following code, when *themes/midnight/index.html* holds an `ng-view`, no view is rendered:

```html
<ng-include src="'themes/midnight/index.html'"></ng-include>
```

However, if I use the code below, the view shows twice:

```html
<ng-include src="'themes/midnight/index.html'"></ng-include>
<div ng-view></div>
```

What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What do you mean "This doesn't show any view related thing:" ?

Comment: I mean ng-view doesn't appear.

Comment: Are you using `template-src` in your routes? A bit more code would be appreciable :-). `ng-view` is for use view `$routeProvider.when(, {template-url: '...'});`

Comment: of course, ng-view outside of ng-include works. only ng-view inside ng-include doesn't appear. When I'm declare ng-view twice inside and outside of ng-include, it appears twice. Very weird to me.

Comment: maybe it's because some kind of isolating, something weird happening with prototypal inheritance. Do you have a jsfiddle/plunker?

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue. Did you resolve it somehow?

Comment: @xil3 This is a scope issue. You should see the scope of angularjs. Unfortunately, I did not solve this problem. I decided not to use ng-include.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This problem occurs due a delayed instantiation of `ng-view` (passing through `ng-include`). In such case the `$route` instantiation is delayed as well, and `$route` will miss the location change event (and routing will not be performed at all).

To bypass this, invoke the `$route` update function on application initialization:

```js
yourApp.run(['$route', function($route)  {
  $route.reload();
}]);
```

Further more, it is sufficient to only include `$route` as a dependency. This will work, too:

```js
yourApp.run(['$route', angular.noop]);
```

<sub>**Source:** the related [issue on github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1213).</sub>

---

Also check out **[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)**, which is intended to specifically deal with the issue of nested views.

Comment: Funny, but it's actually enough to inject $route in the main controller - this fixed the issue for me ))

Comment: @KOHb - this is equivalent to declaring it as a dependency for the app.

Comment: how do you declare dependency for the app? Is this what you mean: `angular.module('Main', [dependencies here])` ?

Comment: @KOHb - I didn't mean dependency at the app level - just using DI to request the service (as shown in the answer).

Comment: that's what I meant, too - just injecting $route fixed it for me, I didn't even have to call $route.reload(). So by adding $route parameter DI kicks in and creates the $route object - and my guess is that something happens in constructor, because that was enough for me. Thanks!